# How can I compile a project in typescript (tsdx) without including the source files?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to compile a typescript project into javascript but for some reason, I keep getting the project's source files in the dist folder. I think it's something to do with my config but I've been through the docs and I can't find something about output folder structure or anything similar sounding. Here's my tsconfig:

```
{
  "include": ["src", "types", "test"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "importHelpers": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*", "node_modules/*"]
    },
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

I am using tsdx and read in one of their issues that some config values are skipped. Is there anyone familiar with the library?

Comment: have you tried using the option `"declaration": false`?

Comment: please provide a folder structure to exactly what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

you can only remove the "src" in your first option called "include"